# Forgot the crockpot lid

Tags: chicken

I was cooking BBQ chicken in the crockpot and didn't put the lid back on . Left to run errands about 3 1/2 hours. And came home to see I left the lid off. Is the chicken ruined?

Comment: Was the crock pot on? What temperature was it at? What temperature is the food inside?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Crockpots are carefully calibrated to come to temperature quickly in the beginning of cooking (this is why they need to be 1/2 to 3/4 full of liquid). Without the lid on it would not come to a safe temperature and you will be at risk of foodborne illness if you eat the chicken or serve it to someone. Sorry! I know that's frustrating to waste good food, but it's better safe than sorry.